# When is @EnableScan required in a DynamoDB repository?

Tags: java, spring, amazon-dynamodb, spring-data, dynamodb-queries

When creating a DynamoDB repository, is the EnableScan annotation required by default?  What is it's functionality?

```java
@EnableScan
public interface DynamoRepository extends CrudRepository<Data, String> {
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is No. You don't need `@EnableScan` all the time. You need it only if you want to query the table with an attribute that's not a partition key.

**For Example:**
Let's say you have a Table called Employee with Partition Key as employee id. You also have attributes like firstName and lastName.

In this case when you use `findById(employeeId)` you don't need `@EnableScan` . But when you use `findByFirstName("John")` then you need `@EnableScan`

You might have noticed the scan feature that's available in DynamoDB UI. `@EnableScan` is similar to the scan feature shown in the snapshot.
[image]

Likewise, you don't need `@EnableScan` when you are querying an index with its partition Key.